# How can i make variables beneath a code global and work for code above in php?

Tags: php, switch-statement

is there a way i can be helped?

i have a very long code :

```
<div class="info-boxx " style="border: 1px solid black; background: <?php echo($color21);?>;">

</div>
$ceeeee21view ="Mastered";
switch ($ceeeee21view) {
                          case "Mastered":
                              $color21="#12c4f9";
                              break;
                          case "Attend To":
                              $color21="#fd0303";
                              break;
                          case "Explore":
                              $color21="#fd7803";
                              break;
                          case "Prompt":
                              $color21="#fdd303";
                              break;
                          case "Unaided":
                              $color21="#58d95e";
                              break;
                          case "Not Applicable":
                             $color21="grey";
                              break;
                          
                          default:                     
                      }
                      /* //////////////////// */
```

it was later that i realized that the switch had to be on top of the #info-boxx for the code to work... please i have written close to 200pages having like 30 to 60 of this type in each page. of this same thing...is there a way to just make the variable $color global? thank i will just search $color21 and replace all with something like global? how do know what to do ..please help.... Thanks, i really hope there is a solution.....

Comment: You should refactor that to a mapping (assoc array) instead of using such a large switch statement.

Comment: do you have any footer.php class or something that is included in all the files?

Comment: Move PHP code to top? I can't see any obvious purpose in having that code in the middle of the view.

Comment: If you use a variable for output like that, no matter what you want to do afterwards is too late. Period.

Comment: Yes @omi shah I have

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should think & plan before you write codes.

*Note that my answer is only a `hack` type solution. And I wouldn't suggest going in this way instead, you should refactor your codes.*

Now to make it work you can do is something like this.

Look at this line, this line will override the background color with the $color21 value for the info-boxx div class. You can add the below single line in all your other files or if you have footer.php file or something that's included in all the other files then you can simply add this to your common footer.php file

```
<style>.info-boxx { background: <?php echo $color21; ?> }</style>
```

Comment: ``error_reporting(0)`` can be used to hide the warnings

Comment: So, you show ``warnings`` to your users in ``production``?

Comment: And, my answer is only a ``fix/alternative`` for what the OP has already made a mistake and when he's not willing to refactor his codes. That's all  :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat, sir if the OP could edit that part isn't he be able to refactor the other part? I am not arguing, if you felt like that,  I am sorry. :)

Comment: yeah... thanks @OMiShah    i just tried that, but i painted everything/every other div #fd0303.... each div has it's own $ceeeee(number)view to work with

Comment: Also can mapping work....  I will just add that on top?

Comment: Use the search and replace option in an editor and apply some logic to fix your mess. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to refactor your code, what everybody suggested to you then you can use the Super-global **$_POST** for this.

For setting use:

```
$_POST['color21']= "#12c4f9";
```

For reading:

```
echo $_POST['color21'];
```

You had only to be sure that the prperty is securely setted at the start because otherwise the user could send perhaps his own values to this property. You had to pay attention that the property name is not used otherwise for datatransfer to your site.